# Angular App, wrapped with Cordova: APK doesn't go past loading screen after installed

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I programmed an app in Angular and built an APK with the help of Cordova. The app works after it is installed on the tablet, however the only thing that shows up is the index.html of www-folder and it does not redirect to the other index.html or in fact start anything of the angular project.

I couldn't find out, how to get rid of this problem or how to redirect the path in the config.xml (if that even works).

How do I solve this problem?

(If you want me to provide any code I will gladly do so, just tell me what you need.) Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: How does the base href look in your index.html file (In Angular app)? `src > index.html`

Comment: The tutorial I followed said to change it from  <base href="/"> to  <base href="./">
I did that, so it is the one with the dot now.

Comment: Yes you need to have it with the dot. My suggestion is to use Chrome's developer tools to see what errors you are getting. Open the `Developer tools > More tools > Remote devices`. Or google `Chrome Remote Devices`.

Comment: That is the problem actually: I'm not getting any errors, but it still doesn't show the part of the app that I want it to show, only the Cordova standard screen

Comment: after you install, in the dom, do you see that angular version thing in the div?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... This is the div in the Cordova index.html:
<div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>

So I would answer yes?